# Add to list of an object with variable key in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Intended for this reduce function to add new `message` into a list of messages with a variable key `userId`.

```js
let state = {
  data: {
    user1: ["message1", "message2"],
    user2: ["message3", "message4"],
  },
};
```

This is what I've got so far:

```js
case types.MESSAGE_FETCHED:
  return {
    ...state,
    data: {
      ...state.data,
      [payload.userId]: [...state.data[payload.userId], payload.message],
    },
  };
```

The error I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: state.data[payload.userId] is not iterable

Comment: [payload.userId]: [...state.data.[payload.userId], payload.message],

Answer (score 0):

I found that, I have to initialize an empty array first.

```js
case types.MESSAGE_FETCHED:
  if (!(payload.userId in state.data)) {
    state.data[payload.userId] = [];
  }
  return {
    ...state,
    data: {
      ...state.data,
      [payload.userId]: [...state.data[payload.userId], payload.message],
    }
  }
```